# Strip some words from wp_title

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wp_title('|',true,'right');

to display taxonomies that were used in the search on my wordpress site, something like breadcrumb, but it gives me also the title of the web site which I don't need.

How can I strip some content from that php output?

The output looks like this:

Taxonomy: Rabbit | Title of the site. (Now I want to strip "Title of the site").

cheers!

Comment: Add a filter to wp_title. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

Comment: can you shou me how to do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133923/change-the-output-of-wp-title

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly this should solve your problem - just put in your variables and your title.

```
$newTitle = substr($yourtitlevar,strstr($yourtitlevar,"Title of the site"));
```

Comment: thx for reply, just tell me where do I put this? What is my title var? (I haven't defined one)

Comment: <?php  $newTitle = substr($ywp_title,strstr($wp_title,"Kursevi stranih jezika")); wp_title('|',true,'right');?> Something like this?